# WATIR unable to locate string with two consecutive whitespace

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Want to locate a string with two consecutive whitespace

like in page http://notepad.cc/manele85

string "Google" has two consecutive whitespace between 'o' and 'g'

my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

b.goto "http://notepad.cc/manele85"
puts b.div(:text => "Goo  gle").text
```

outputs:

```
unable to locate element, using {:text=>"Goo  gle", :tag_name=>"div"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watir normalize's spaces when locating elements by text. If you set `$DEBUG` to true, you can see that Watir is creating the following XPath for `b.div(:text => "Goo  gle")`:

```
.//div[normalize-space()='Goo  gle']
```

Because of the `normalize-space`, Watir will treat multiple consecutive spaces as a single space.

As a result, when locating the element, you should remove the consecutive spaces in the locator:

```
b.div(:text => "Goo gle").exists?
#=> true

b.div(:text => "Goo gle").text
#=> "Goo gle"
```

If you do want to locate the element using the multiple spaces, you will have to get an element collection and check the text values:

```
div = b.divs.find { |div| div.text == 'Goo gle' }
div.text
#=> "Goo gle"
```

Comment: Hi Justin, it works! And want to know more about this: why Watir normalize's spaces? Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: I would guess that Watir normalizes spaces since the browser usually displays multiple consecutive spaces as a single space. There is no way to turn off the normalization (other than monkey patching). However, you could create a custom locator using `find` (example added to answer).